# Does C++ deep-initialize class members?

Tags: c++, data-structures, oop

I have a class in C++ with the following member:

```
map< someEnum, vector<SomeObject*>* > someMap
```

So I have a map that gives me a vector of objects for each enumeration I have. For the life of me, I cannot understand how C++ is initializing these objects. Does it deep initialize them by default? If not, what do I need to do?

I'm getting segmentation faults no matter how I try to do this (and I have tried *everything*), so I'm guessing I'm missing something conceptually.

---

I should note that I tried to use:

```
map< someEnum, vector<SomeObject*> > someMap
```

as well and that didn't work as well. In this case, does C++ deep-initialize the vector?

Comment: Can you also post how you are filling the map object?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The rule is: If an STL container contains **pointers to objects**, it it does **not** create objects on heap and assign them to these pointers. If, however, it contains **objects** themselves, it **does** call the default constructor of each contained object and thus initialises them.

What you have here is a map containing pointers (no matter what kind). So do not expect the map to make these pointers to point to memory.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the map gives you a pointer to a vector of objects. If you try to use the map via

`mymap[MY_ENUM]->push_back(whatever);`

before you initialize, you'll get a segfault. You either need to initialize the vector first

`mymap[MY_ENUM] = new vector<SomeObject*>;`

or, *much* better, just make the map give you a plain ol' vector

`map <someEnum, vector<SomeObject*> > mymap;`

When you first call `mymap[MY_ENUM]`, the vector will be default-initialized (with size zero). Is the problem that you're trying to use the entries of the vector before you enlarge it, e.g.,

`mymap[MY_ENUM][2] = whatever;`

You still need to use `push_back` or `resize`, or something that gives you some space.

Comment: Jesse thanks, I editing my question in response to your answer.

Comment: mymap[MY_ENUM][2] = whatever;

is still incorrect, you'll be setting 3rd vector<SomeObject*> instance in this case. Correct way to access third element is

( *mymap[MY_ENUM] )[2] = whatever;

Comment: @Tanveer: Your proposed syntax assumes we continue to use map<SomeEnum, vector<SomeObject*>*>.  But Jesse suggests using the much more sensible map<SomeEnum, vector<SomeObject*> > instead, in which case mymap[MY_ENUM][2] is indeed the correct syntax.

Answer (score 2):

You won't get vector's of SomeObject pointers tucked nicely inside that map by just declaring an object.

Instead, you'll have to proceed like this:

```
map< someEnum, vector< SomeObject* >* > someMap;

someMap [ somevalue ] = new vector< SomeObject* >;

someMap [ somevalue ] -> push_back( new SomeObject );
```

Your pain won't end just here. You'll need to clean it up properly before the map goes out of scope with something like this.

```
// Untested code, may not even compile.
for( map< someEnum, vector< SomeObject* >* >::iterator iter = someMap.begin( ) ; iter != someMap.end( ) ; ++i )
{
     for( vector< SomeObject* >::iterator v = iter -> second -> begin( ) ; v != iter -> second -> end( ) ; ++v )
         delete *v;

     delete iter -> second;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll get an empty map that can store std::vector*, referenced by someEnum.  The empty map will contain NO vectors.  It's up to you to create a new vector object (with new is the safest way) and store its pointer in the map.

It might be nitpicking, but if the enums are a fixed (small) size then why a map for them?  A simple array will be easier to get your noodle around and likely more space and CPU efficient unless you have sparse population.

C++ can't initialise the content of the map or vectors because it doesn't know what *you* want to store there.

Comment: I think a map is a good idea here, so you have a key-indexed vector of sorts.  Being small, efficiency issues are not so important.

Comment: @Gorpik: Adam's point is that a vector also works as a "key-indexed vector" -- indeed it works much faster and uses less memory -- provided all the keys are small integers.

Comment: @j: It is only more space efficient if you have dense population, even in smaller sets.  I was asuming from 'enum' that there is a dense population and a small set.